# Como acceder a relacion de relacion en eloquent laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Tengo 3 modelos: Order,Productos y Categorias. Una orden puede tener muchos productos y un producto puede estar relacionado con muchas ordenes y un Producto puede tener 1 sola categoria, las relaciones son estas:

```
class Order extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function products(){
        return $this->morphToMany(Product::class, 'productable')->withPivot('quantity');
      
}


class Product extends Model
{
    use HasFactory,SoftDeletes;

    public function category(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class)->withTrashed();
    }

    public function orders(){
        return $this->morphedByMany(Order::class, 'productable');
    }

}


class Category extends Model
{
    use HasFactory, SoftDeletes;

    public function products(){
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
    }

}
```

Estoy intentando obtener las ordenes en cierto intervalo de fechas, obteniendo tambien los productos que tiene con su respectiva categoria, hasta ahora solo puedo obtener las ordenes con sus productos, asi:

```
public function Sales($start_date=null,$end_date=null){
        $sales = Order::With(['products'])
        ->select('id','total','iva','sale_date','created_at')
        ->whereBetween('orders.sale_date',[$start_date,$end_date])
        ->orderBy('orders.created_at','desc');
        return $sales->get();
    }
```

Puedo acceder a la categoria del producto en la vista blade con `$product->category->name`, pero quiero traer la categoria dentro de la consulta por temas de rendimiento, hay alguna forma de hacerlo?

Comment: Podes hacer el eager load como está explicado en [Nested Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#nested-eager-loading). Lo que no entiendo de lo que muestras es por qué hiciste la relación polimórfica entre Order y Product, ya que con un Many To Many sería suficiente

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ tengo una tabla Cart que tambien usa la tabla "productables", por eso la relacion polimorfica, muchas gracias por tu respuesta, logre lo que queria :)

Answer (score 2):

Solo tuve que seguir la seccion de la documentacion: [Nested eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#nested-eager-loading)

```
public function Sales($start_date=null,$end_date=null){
        $sales = Order::With(['products.category'])
        ->select('id','total','iva','sale_date','created_at')
        ->whereBetween('orders.sale_date',[$start_date,$end_date])
        ->orderBy('orders.created_at','desc');
        return $sales->get();
    }
```